# Google app engine json response as REST

Tags: python, json, google-app-engine

How can I response a page as a json page? Is the code below correct?

```
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app
import json

class JsonPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.header['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
        self.response.out.write(json.dumps(['foo', {'bar': ('baz', None, 1.0, 2)}]))

application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('json', JsonPage)], debug=True)

def main():
    run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I get the following error message:

```
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2012-05-06 14:10:01 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

---

After make some changes to the code, I got the following error, seem like the dumps object cannot be found in the json module :

```
<pre>Traceback (most recent call last):
  File &quot;/opt/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/webapp/_webapp25.py&quot;, line 701, in __call__
    handler.get(*groups)
  File &quot;/home/kelvin/workspace/cloudnuts/json.py&quot;, line 8, in get
    self.response.out.write(json.dumps(['foo', {'bar': ('baz', None, 1.0, 2)}]))
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'dumps'
</pre>
```

Comment: Are ypu running on python2.7 or python2.5?

Comment: I am using Python 2.7 and Google app engine sdk 1.6.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably change the code to:

```
application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/json', JsonPage)], debug=True)
```

---

As for your json problem, do you have a local file named json.py? it will override json package import.

Comment: Thanks. self.response.header['Content-Type'] should be self.response.headers['Content-Type'].

Comment: I have change that, now I got some error mention at the bottom of the question.

Comment: Thanks, my bad, I am using the same name json. Changed it, now getting a json response.